# How do I correctly return an unmodifiable object reference from function in C++?

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference

I am trying to return a const object from a function so that I can get information from it, but nothing can be changed once it has been created. I have the following code

```
    Sprite const& GetSprite() const {
        return *m_sprite;
    }


    std::unique_ptr<Sprite> m_sprite;
    int test = 5;
```

Somewhere else in the code I am calling this `GetSprite` function

```
Sprite sprite = entity->GetSprite();
sprite.test = 6;
```

This seems to compile fine and after stepping through the value in `test` is actually changed. I would have assumed that the object returned from `GetSprite` would not allow me to modify the object, but the const qualifier seems to be dropped?

Am I doing this wrong or is there a different approach to achieve this?

Comment: You are thinking of `Sprite & sprite = entity->GetSprite();` which won't compile.

Comment: `Sprite sprite = entity->GetSprite();` creates a *copy*, which is modifiable.

Comment: This is what you probably want: `const Sprite& sprite = ...`

Comment: Oh of course. @UnholySheep is there a way to prevent being able to make this copy so I don't unintentionally do this?

Comment: Pretty hard to prevent accidental copying short of explicitly removing the copy constructor and assignment operator. `Sprite (const Sprite  &) = delete;` and `Sprite &  operator=(const Sprite  &) = delete;` This, of course, makes it harder to intentionally copy.

Comment: @jjmcc Since you didn't modify the object that you said shouldn't be modified, it's not clear why you'd want to prevent it. Can you be more precise about exactly what you want to avoid? Is it the cost of the copy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Sprite sprite = entity->GetSprite();
```

this creates a copy of the `Sprite` object `GetSprite` returns, using the copy-consturctor of `Sprite.

Editing the copy should not cause the original to be modified, unless you have written `Sprite` wrong, or you get confused between reference, value and pointer semantics.

```
Sprite const& sprite = entity->GetSprite();
```

this gets a reference to the contained `Sprite` through which you cannot modify it.

If you want to block copying of `Sprite`s, you can do:

```
Sprite(Sprite const&) = delete;
```

but I'd advise allowing moving of `Sprite`s:

```
Sprite(Sprite&&) = default;
```

especially pre-[c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) (when guaranteed elision makes it less important).